# Is there an RDD transform function that looks at neighboring elements?

Tags: java, apache-spark

Does anyone know if there is a way during a transform to look at neighboring elements in a sorted RDD? I know I can collect and then do such an operation as the one in the below example, however it kind of defeats the purpose of a distributed system and I'm trying to leverage the fact that it's distributed.

Example:

RDD of (string name, int val)  map to RDD of (string name, int val, int diff)

such that:

```
name | val     becomes ->      name | val | diff (current - prior)
a    | 3                       a    | 3   | 3
b    | 6                       b    | 6   | 3
c    | 4                       c    | 4   | -2
d    | 20                      d    | 20  | 16
```

Comment: Side note: for anyone trying to use lag and lead with DataFrames, that feature is only available for Spark versions 1.4 and up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably <s>the most efficient approach</s> simplest approach is to convert a RDD to data frame and use lag:

```
case class NameValue(name: String, value: Int)
val rdd = sc.parallelize(
    NameValue("a", 3) ::  NameValue("b", 6) :: 
    NameValue("c", 4) ::  NameValue("d", 20) :: Nil)

val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd)
df.registerTempTable("df")
sqlContext.sql("""SELECT name, value,
                  value - lag(value) OVER (ORDER BY name, value) lag
                  FROM df""").show
```

Unfortunately at this moment window functions without `PARTITION BY` clause move all data to a single partition so it is particularly useful if you have large dataset.

Using low level operations you could use `zipWithIndex` followed by `flatMap` and `groupByKey`:

```
case class NameValueWithLag(name: String, value: Int, lag: Int)
val cnt = rdd.count() - 1

rdd.
    zipWithIndex.
    flatMap{case (x, i) => (0 to 1).map(lag => (i - lag, (i, x)))}.
    groupByKey.
    filter{ case (k, v) => k != cnt}.
    values.
    map(vals => {
        val sorted = vals.toArray.sortBy(_._1).map(_._2)
        if (sorted.length == 1) {
            NameValueWithLag(sorted(0).name, sorted(0).value, sorted(0).value)
        } else {
            NameValueWithLag(
               sorted(1).name, sorted(1).value,
               sorted(1).value - sorted(0).value
            )
        }
    })
```

Edit:

If you don't mind using developers API there you can try `RDDFunctions.sliding` but it requires manual processing

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.rdd.RDDFunctions._

val first = rdd.first match {
  case NameValue(name, value) => NameValueWithLag(name, value, value)
}

sc.parallelize(Seq(first)).union(rdd
  .sliding(2)
  .map(a => NameValueWithLag(a(1).name, a(1).value, a(1).value - a(0).value)))
```

Comment: Data frames probably wouldn't work, as what I'm doing is a bit more complex and checking a few more neighbors out (wanted to focus on the main issue). The second approach looks like it would work, but I need to convert that to Java. If the toArray isn't a rdd collect() call then this should work. If you beat me to writing this out in Java, that would be appreciated...  need to dive over to the office.

Comment: I wouldn't discard data frames yet. There are both highly optimized and quite flexible. `lag` can take a second parameter so you can easily get a more neighbors if you want, there is `lead` to look ahead, and you can (almost) plain rdd back. `.toArray` doesn't collect. It works locally and is just to get access to `sortBy`. Regarding Java you're out of luck. I don't use it unless I really have to.

Comment: I don't know if this is just unsupported, a bug or something else, but I can't do df.selectExpr("lag(VAL) as lva") but df.selectExpr("abs(VAL) as lva") works. Should I start another topic for this?

Comment: Yes, I think that another topic will be better. Window specifications are rather tricky.

Comment: It turns out, that functionality was introduced in version 1.4...  anyway, upgrading from 1.3 introduce another set of problems with data frames. Thanks for the help, I'm going with the second option!