# populate Rows (With moving averages ) is Spark SQL 1.6.0 Imputing rows

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have Data like this as DF  , I want to populate Rows with moving averages of column2(with window of last 2 ) untill i reach column1 as 2000

input DataFrame :

```
Column1 column2 column3
100          2       89
200          6       102
300          10      105
400          15      125
```

expected result DataFrame :

```
Column1 column2 column3
100          2       89
200          6       102
300          10      105
400          15      125
500      (10+15)/2  (105+ 125) /2
600   (15 + 25/2)/2 (125+ 230/2 )/2
```

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31538007/is-there-an-rdd-transform-function-that-looks-at-neighboring-elements

Comment: @david Griffin Thanks for the post ...

in my case scenario is that i needed to keep the rows untill column1 value 400 as it is. but from column1 value 500 upto 20000 i need to generate rows , with taking average of last two values ...